# Multiple ExpectedException in MsTest

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

How can I put multiple `ExpectedExceptionin` in a MSTest?

something like this

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
[ExpectedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
```

because it shows me `ExpectedException` in double error

Comment: If you look at the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx you would see that the attribute is not meant to be used multiple times.

Comment: You are right, Thanks for the link so how can we achieve this?

Comment: Should I run test on each exception separately?

Comment: Yes separate tests with separate expectations. You are the on in control of the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [ExpectedExceptionAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) you would see that the attribute is not meant to be used multiple times on a method.

> This attribute can be specified on a method. There can be only one instance of this attribute on a method.

To answer the follow up question

> Should I run test on each exception separately?

Yes. Separate tests with separate expectations. You are in control of the test and should arrange them accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't is the simple answer.

[MSDN ExpectedExceptionAttribute Class Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks)